# How to resolve an NPE during mock of resultSet.getUninterruptibly

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to create some junits for a dao class using junit5, but i keep getting an NPE. Below is my junit.

```
  void saveObject) throws ParseException, TimeoutException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Object rec16 = getRec16_3();
    Mockito.when(cassandraSession.getOrCreateStatement(any(String.class)))
        .thenReturn(preparedStatement);
    Mockito.when(preparedStatement.bind()).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(boundStatement.setString(anyInt(), any(String.class))).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(boundStatement.setTimestamp(anyInt(), any(Date.class))).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(boundStatement.setLong(anyInt(), anyLong())).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(boundStatement.setDouble(anyInt(), any(Double.class))).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(boundStatement.setInt(anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(boundStatement);
    Mockito.when(cassandraSuppSession.getCassandraSession()).thenReturn(session);
    Mockito.when(session.executeAsync(any(BoundStatement.class))).thenReturn(resultSetFuture);
    Mockito.when(resultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(anyLong(), any(TimeUnit.class))).thenReturn(resultSet);
    objectDao.saveObject(rec16);
  }
```

And the part where it's failing is in the below method on `getUninterruptibly(CASSANDRA_QUERY_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

```
private void executeBatch(BatchStatement objectBatch, String tableName) {
    try {
      cassandraSuppSession
          .getCassandraSession()
          .executeAsync(objectBatch)
          .getUninterruptibly(CASSANDRA_QUERY_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Exception inserting into " + tableName, e);
    } finally {
      objectBatch.clear();
    }
  }
```

Turning the `executeAsync` call into a synchronous call (`execute`) and removing the `getUinterruptibly` method allows the junit to run successfully. So i know my issue is within this block, but no idea how to resolve it. I do want to keep the async call instead of switching to a sync call. Any ideas?

Comment: `BoundStatement` vs `BatchStatement` looks suspicious.

Comment: Yup that was it lol. Thank you